# vue2 - '$store is undefined' when used in component

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Hey i am trying to make my seed for cordova projects.

Everything was going good till `this.$store` in `src/components/Main.vue` is undefined i have no more
clues why cuz in other app it was working and never had this issue maybe someone more experianced with vue2 could help me out.

Cheers.

[This is full code repo](https://github.com/rpdiss/cordova-vue2-seed)

edit:

If i pass $store from template or use this.$store in created store is working.

Comment: Add your code or at least relevant part of it here. The provided link is broken that's way we prefer the code here.

Comment: @JorgeCampos i fixed link anyways if i add method and use this.$store it not gonna work

Comment: I'm new to vue, I think you shouldn't be using `this` keyword for the store. But it is just a guess. Oh, the Vue Land channel in the discord app really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I was using arrow function in methods that was an issue.